# Token unknown -end Trigger Firebird

Tags: firebird

I tried create a trigger in Firebird ISQL tool with this syntax, but I'm getting this message error:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -104
-Token unknown - line 6, column 1
-end
```

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dataweb_inve
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 0
ON INVE01
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dataweb (CVE_ART, DESCR, EXIST, NUM_MON, CVE_BITA) SELECT CVE_ART, DESCR, EXIST, NUM_MON, CVE_BITA FROM INVE01 ORDER BY FCH_ULTCOM desc rows 1
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Statements inside PSQL (Firebird Procedural SQL) must be terminated by a semicolon. Your insert is missing that semicolon, so the Firebird parser finds an `END` in an insert statement where it doesn't expect one, and raises the *token unknown* error.
2. ISQL - by default - uses the semicolon to determine when a statement is complete and can be sent to the Firebird server for execution. Given PSQL uses semicolons internally to separate statements, you need to instruct ISQL to use a different [statement terminator](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-terminator) using the [`SET TERM`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-set-term) command.

In short, you need to use the following in ISQL:

```sql
set term #;
CREATE TRIGGER dataweb_inve
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 0
ON INVE01
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dataweb (CVE_ART, DESCR, EXIST, NUM_MON, CVE_BITA) 
    SELECT CVE_ART, DESCR, EXIST, NUM_MON, CVE_BITA 
    FROM INVE01 
    ORDER BY FCH_ULTCOM desc 
    rows 1;
END#
set term ;#
```

As an aside, the way you select the row to insert is rather suspect, as it is possible a newer row exists in `INVE01` than the one the trigger fired for. If you want to insert values of the row the trigger fired for, then use the [`NEW` context](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql-oldnew).

Your trigger would then look like:

```sql
set term #;
CREATE TRIGGER dataweb_inve
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 0
ON INVE01
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dataweb (CVE_ART, DESCR, EXIST, NUM_MON, CVE_BITA) 
    values (new.CVE_ART, new.DESCR, new.EXIST, new.NUM_MON, new.CVE_BITA);
END#
set term ;#
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly and I didn't considerate use NEW, I think is a better practice.